# generated sound through AVAudioPlayer sounds distorted

Tags: xcode

I have an app where you press a button you hear a sound. I created the sound myself, .wav file, not compressed and it sounds fine in my DAW. I made sure it's not clipping so I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the creation of the sound. However, can it be possible that Xcode reduces the quality of the sound and compresses it automatically? I'm just trying to figure out why my sound is not sounding good.

Anyone any idea on how to make sure I don't loose sound quality?

Comment: Is the sound, when it's playing on the iOS device, clipping?

Comment: It sounds close to like it's clipping, yes, but I'm not sure if it is. Then I went back to my DAW to check if I didn't miss anything, while recording nothing clipped nor when I bounced it. I might try to record it again if I can't find another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clipping should be easily identified. It sounds like pops or clicks and sticks out like a sore thumb.  I’m a little confused by the ambiguity about it clipping or not.

Anyways, I had an issue where my wav audio file would clip when I played using `AVAudioPlayer` in iOS.  When I played the audio on my mac, there was no clipping. After experimenting a bit (changing sample rates, mixing down to mono, etc ) what I ending up needing to do was to edit the sound by reducing the amplitude.  As far as a reduction in sound quality, I didn’t notice any problems with that, so perhaps I was not having the same issue as you are.  Regardless, I thought I would pass my experience along so as to give you an avenue to try in resolving your issue. Good luck!